# bind props data into global mixin

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-mixin

I have global mixin with data from getters,like:

I want to bind "currentTheme" on all components which one has prop with name "theme"

I think I need hook `beforeMount`, because on previous hooks I can't use computed data

```es6
import Vue from "vue";

import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

Vue.mixin({
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      currentTheme: "getCurrentTheme"
    })
  },
  beforeMount() {}
});
```

How can I do it better and with reactivity?

Comment: You can bind the getters as computed properties as you have, but you need to ensure that you have initialized the Vuex data *before* you access the getters (otherwise whatever data your getters needs won't be there).

Comment: ye,accordingly i used beforeMount , on this hook vuex initializated already,but how correctly do binding idknw

Comment: what does "idknw" mean?

Comment: sorry,i mean "i dont know"

Answer (score 0):

In `created` hook check whether or not the component has `theme` prop. If it has, then [`$set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set) value of `currentTheme` to `this.$data`.

```
import Vue from "vue";

import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

Vue.mixin({
  created() {
    if (this.$options._propKeys.includes("theme")) {
      this.$set(this.$data, "key", this.$store.getters.getCurrentTheme);
    }
  }
});
```

For the following `props`:

[image: Props: {theme: String, foo: Number}]

`this.$options._propKeys` looks like this:

[image: theme, foo]

Comment: not bad idea,but i use components with props theme,not data,
in fact, I need to functionally implement this: :theme="currentTheme.name"

Comment: What's the problem? Using this code you can implement it.